# Field result value from the request?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables. Table with reports and phrases (search phrases). The report table has a date field and other results (not important). When writing a sql query, connect a table with phrases and take the name and frequency from it, then the fields should be built according to the dates that are in the reports (distinct). How to do this ?

All I was able to do is the usual JOIN, but what to do with the dates I don't know:

```sql
SELECT 
reports.url,
reports.position,
phrases.name,
phrases.counter


FROM reports JOIN phrases ON reports.phrase_id = phrases.id
AND reports.site_id = 98
```

The idea of the sample should be more distinct, but as it is there insert ?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT report_date FROM reports WHERE site_id=98
```

The idea is to get something:

```
phrase | counter | 07.06.2019 | 09.06.2019 | 10.06.2019
buy..     100           90              1          89
sell...   50            12              3          19
```

The numbers below the dates are `reports.position`.

(yandex translate on russian)

Comment: The idea is to get something like:
![результат] (https://i.ibb.co/TYmCpVQ/image.png)

Comment: Use https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ for questions in Russian.

Comment: SO is an english only website. Please translate your question

Comment: Most people on this site don't speak or read Russian.  I strongly recommend that you translate your question to English.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Please, edit your question to include a sample data (proper table structure perhaps) and the desired results.